# Using XmlTextWriter to write value with a new line (keep proper indent) in c#

Tags: c#, xmltextwriter

what I want is like this:

```
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
        value
      </c>
    </b>
  </a>
```

I've tried:
  WriteValue()/WriteString() will not start a new line: `"<c>value</c>"`
  WriteWhitespace(Environment.NewLine) will not keep the indent:

```
  <a>
    <b>
      <c>
  value
  </c>
    </b>
  </a>
```

For some reason I have to use XmlTextWriter.

Comment: Try the properties, writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
     writer.Indentation = 4;

Comment: you may misunderstood, I've already use formatting, so the a-b-c will keep indent, but when I want add a value in a new line, the value cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use XmlWriterSettings. see the code sample

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.IndentChars = "\t";
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"sample.xml", settings);
        writer.WriteStartElement("a");
        writer.WriteStartElement("b");
        writer.WriteStartElement("c");
        writer.WriteValue("value");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();
```

Comment: thanks, but sorry I have to use XmlTextWriter to write XML segments, which cannot use the settings. Is there any solution for XmlTextWriter?

Comment: If you can post your code sample that will help to check

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a small custom writer to accomplish that. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542165/5114784